# How many copies of DLL code are in memory when they are loaded at different virtual addresses?

Tags: windows, dll, paging

I understand that when a DLL is loaded into a process space, Windows would first try to load at the preferred address, and if it fails it would perform relocation.  Suppose that I have a DLL which is loaded into two different processes, but it happens that the DLL cannot be loaded at the same virtual address in both processes.  Does that mean the OS have to have two relocated version of the DLL code in memory (backed up by pagefile instead of the original DLL file)

Comment: Some related info here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170119-00/?p=95215#:~:text=If%20a%20DLL%20must%20be,backed%20by%20the%20page%20file.&text=For%20example%2C%20the%20page%20file,of%20pages%20with%20no%20fixups.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that loading DLL into different addresses would cause extra relocated code to be stored in memory.  But only those code pages that required fixing up:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/why-should-i-even-bother-to-use-dlls-in-my-system